# Django Not Recognizing URLs

Tags: python, django

I am getting a 404 error for a few of my URLs in my django project.  For example:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
Using the URLconf defined in some_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$ [name='home']
^admin/$
```

But I haven't changed anything to the file.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'views.index',name='home',),

    url(r'^admin/$', include(admin.site.urls)),


)
```

This problem seemed to come after I installed Django Evolve.  Not sure if that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your request url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin`, but your urlpattern is `url(r'^admin/$', include(admin.site.urls))`.

There is an extra `/` in the urlpattern.

If you want to include other URLConfs, here's an example to include other URLconfs:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... snip ...
    url(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
    url(r'^community/', include('django_website.aggregator.urls')),
    url(r'^contact/', include('django_website.contact.urls')),
    # ... snip ...
)
```

As Burhan correctly pointed out, you need to remove the trailing `$` so that `include` could work.

The reason is because in regex `trailing $ matches right after the last character in the string`.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is not correct, it should be:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the settings file.  There was a merge problem with what I had and another developer had.

The /$ wasn't related to this problem.  I added it when I was trouble shooting.

Comment: yes, but not the reason why the error was coming up. for example if you had the /$, there would be a different error.  But yes, you are right, this is a problem.  thanks for your help.